# White-line artifacts in ggplot2 plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

(Edit: now submitted as [ggplot2 issue #4183](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4183).)

I'm not sure exactly what conditions cause this to happen, but here's a pretty small example derived from the real plot that I was working on when I ran into this:

```
library(ggplot2)

d = data.frame(x = seq(0, 2, len = 2500))
d$y = d$x^2

ggsave("~/plot.png", width = 3, height = 4, dpi = 90,
    ggplot(d) +
    geom_col(aes(x, y), width = max(diff(d$x))) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()))
```

With ggplot2 3.3.2 on R 3.6.2 on Linux, I get this:

[image: Output of the code above]

How do I reliably avoid getting vertical white lines like the one at about *x* = 0.8 above?

Comment: I ran your code and I didn't get thw white lines. Try updating `ggplot2`

Comment: @Duck But CRAN doesn't have a newer version than 3.3.2. Are you running a prerelease?

Comment: I noticed we have same version `ggplot2_3.3.2`. The only thing that could produce that issue is a conflict with other packages. You can try re starting `R` and only loading `ggplot2` and reproduce the plot!

Comment: @Duck I can reproduce the error with a fresh `R --vanilla`.

Comment: Using R 4.0.1 and `ggplot2` version 3.3.2 I do not see the lines (same as @Duck).  Could be an issue with the R version/ggplot version interaction?

Comment: Should we expect the OS to make a difference? I get the same line in Ubuntu, but haven't tested in Windows or Mac.

Comment: @rushgeo I don't know, but I figure it's possible that OS makes a difference because it could be a bug in a low-level graphics library. My best guess right now is that R 4.0 fixes this somehow.

Comment: I'm getting the same line using R 4.0.2 from the docker image rocker/geospatial

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with your visual trick of using `width` that somewhere somehow there's a rounding error? The width is pretty small at `0.0008003201` and computer dislikes floating point number... I would stick to using `geom_ribbon()` to produce the same graph: `ggplot(d) + geom_ribbon(aes(x, ymin=0, ymax=y))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ggplot has decreed this a won't-fix, but it can be worked around by increasing the width with something like `geom_col(aes(x, y), width = max(diff(d$x)) * 1.05, position = "identity")`:

[image: New output]